# Alternative to using substring? Substring makes it too easy to make repeating mistake when typing it

Tags: c#

Is there a simplier, shorter cut way to this than using substring()?   I'm trying to make it less error cuz it is too easy to make mistake when typing the LastIndexOf and Length, plus counter.

```
string filepath = "c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\file1.jpg";
string file = "";

file = filepath.SubString(
    (filepath.LastIndexOf("\\")+1), 
    (filepath.Length - filepath.LastIndexOf("\\")+1)
);
```

I want to get this value "file1.jpg".

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

```
string filepath = "c:\folder1\folder2\folder3\file1.jpg";
string file = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

---

Another option for non path based records is using the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) function.

```
string longString = "The cat jump over the brown fox";
string[] splitString = longString.Split(new char[] {' '}); //Splits the string in to array elements wherever it see a space;
string lastWord = splitString[splitString.Length - 1]; //Could throw a error is the length is less than 1
string lastTwoWords = String.Join(" ", splitString.Skip(splitString.Length - 2)); //Could throw a error if the length is less than 2
```

Comment: Neat!  One more question.  What if it's a string "The cat jump over the brown fox" and I want to get this "brown fox".  Is there a way to do this as well?

Comment: See my update, it gets the last word and the last two words by first splitting it in to an array.

Answer (score 4):

This function may help you : [Path.GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

There is [GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension.aspx) too if you don't need the file extension, and [GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) to get the extension (:

Comment: What about getting extenstion only as well?  :-)

Comment: @fletchsod http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx ;)